# Unable to create Test Set Using Java Rally Rest API

Tags: java, rest, rally

I need to create new Test set in Iteration and I have given Object ID for a Iteration based on its Formatted ID.
I am using following code to create TestSet. But it doesn't give any result "Errors:[Could not read: Object not found for Object ID: null]"

```
JsonObject createTestCase = new JsonObject();
createTestCase.addProperty("Name", "New Test Set");
createTestCase.addProperty("DefectStatus", "NONE");
createTestCase.addProperty("TaskStatus", "NONE");
createTestCase.addProperty("TestCaseStatus", "ALL_RUN_ALL_PASSING");
createTestCase.addProperty("Iteration", findIterationObjectId("TestProject-PI-2-Iteration 1"));

CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testset", createTestCase);
CreateResponse createResponse = null;
try{
    createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);
    if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
         String createReference = createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString();                             
   }
} catch(Exception e){
  //error
  }
```

Getting Object ID for a Iteration based on its Formatted ID

```
 private String findIterationObjectId(String iterationFormattedID) {      
    QueryRequest iterationRequest = new QueryRequest("Iteration");
    iterationRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("ObjectID"));

    iterationRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "contains", iterationFormattedID));
    QueryResponse testSetQueryResponse = null;
    try {
        testSetQueryResponse = restApi.query(iterationRequest);
        if (testSetQueryResponse.wasSuccessful() && testSetQueryResponse.getResults().size() > 0) {
            String objectId = testSetQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("ObjectID").toString();                
            return objectId;
        } else {
            //error
        }
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        //error
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In wsapi whenever you are setting object relationships you always use their ref uri, not just the object id.  Refs are of the format `/<type>/<objectid>`.

So in your case this should work:

```
createTestCase.addProperty("Iteration", "/iteration/" + findIterationObjectId("..."));
```